# How to Replace innerHTML of all divs via getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add custom html code to adblock users in div called "cfmonitor".
Currently I am using Below Mentioned Script.

```
<script> 
  window.onload = function(){   
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var ad = document.querySelector("ins.adsbygoogle");
           if (ad && ad.innerHTML.replace(/s/g, "").length == 0) {
             ad.style.cssText = 'display:block !important'; 
                document.getElementById("cfmonitor").innerHTML = 'html code goes here';
      }
    }, 500);
  }; 
</script>
```

The Issue - This Code just replace only first cfmonitor div with my custom html code. I have multiple divs of "cfmonitor". How can i replace all "cfmonitor" divs with my custom html code?
Tried to experiment a lot but failed, anyone can help me out?

Comment: With id you can't because javascript returns only the first element with the searched id

Comment: use `querySelectorAll` instead of just `querySelector`, then loop the results like you would a `getElementsByTagName` result set.

Comment: can you please modify it for me? i don't know have much knowledge in coding.

Comment: Exactly as @Marco Morelli Moretti said: ids are supposed to be unique. In your case, you might want to instead use a class name, and query by that instead...

Comment: @Honeysingh i suggest you to add cfmonitor as class and then use getElementsByClassName

Comment: i have tried to change cfmonitor to class and tried getElementsByClassName instead of getElementById, it didn't done any changes in page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use class names as others suggested. And you will then need to iterate through the array of elements that is returned.

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('cfmonitor');
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].innerHTML = 'hi';
}
```

Comment: jquery is tagged, so looping is not needed.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Pretty sure OP probably thinks that jQuery and JS are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving the `cfmonitor` from an element ID to a class. Element IDs need to be unique as well. If you do that, you can change this:

```
<div class="cfmonitor">how</div>
<div class="cfmonitor">are</div>
<div class="cfmonitor">you</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="cfmonitor">GREAT!</div>
<div class="cfmonitor">GREAT!</div>
<div class="cfmonitor">GREAT!</div>
```

By using this code (Using jQuery since you tagged it)

```
$(".cfmonitor").html("GREAT!");
```

Comment: OP was using classes already... (code speaks louder than titles)

Comment: Thanks for your reply by tried this code, don't seems to work

Comment: <script> 
  window.onload = function(){   
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var ad = document.querySelector("ins.adsbygoogle");
           if (ad && ad.innerHTML.replace(/s/g, "").length == 0) {
             ad.style.cssText = 'display:block !important'; 
                $(".cfmonitor").html("html code");
      }
    }, 500);
  }; 
</script>

Comment: there is no markup in the OP. all i see to indicate that it's an id is getElementById. what am i missing that led you to believe there are classes?

Comment: Add `console.log("test");` to inside your `if` block to see if it runs at all.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I didn't believe there were classes, which is why I suggested making classes instead of using cfmonitor as an ID.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I think I misunderstood him anyways.

Answer (score -1):

If would be best if you use Id(s) names on the divs and then connect the javascript using getElementById

```
<div id="first_div">THIS IS THE WORDING YOU WANT TO CHANGE</div>
<div id="first_div">THIS IS THE WORDING YOU WANT TO CHANGE</div>
<div id="first_div">THIS IS THE WORDING YOU WANT TO CHANGE</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('first_div').innerHTML = "Change Text to the following ";
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot have several items of with the same `id` attribute!